# Finite expectation when probability of singularity is zero

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory, expectation

Assume $X$ is a random variable with probability density function $f(x)=2  x e^{-x^2}$ and $0 \leq L\leq1$ is another random variable with $L\geq1-\frac{1}{4X^2}$. Using the law of total expectation:

\begin{align}
E[L]&=E[L|X>\psi] P(X>\psi)+ E[L|X\leq\psi] P(X\leq\psi)\\
&\geq E[L|X>\psi] P(X>\psi)\\
&= E[L|X>\psi] (1- e^{-\psi^2})\\
&=E[1-1/(4X^2)|d>\psi] (1- e^{\psi^2})\\
&\geq (1-1/(4\psi^2)) (1- e^{-\psi^2})
\end{align}

Therefore, with $\psi=\sqrt{2}$, $$E[L]\geq (7/8)(1-e^{-2})>0.$$ I understand from this equation that although $L$ has singularity at $X=0$, since the event $X=0$ occurs with zero probability, the expectation of $L$ remains finite. But, instead of using the law of total expectation, is there a shorter way to prove $E[L]>0$? I mean, by only using the integral for the expectation and considering the fact that the event $X=0$ happens with zero probability. My integral solution is useless because it proves $E[L]>-\infty$:

\begin{align}
E[L] &\geq \int\limits_{x=0}^{\infty}(1-1/4x^{2}) 2xe^{-x^2}dx=1-0.5\int\limits_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{ x} dx \to -\infty
\end{align}

The integral version of my first solution is:

\begin{align}
E[L] \geq \int\limits_{x=0}^{\infty}(1-1/4x^{2}) 2xe^{-x^2}dx &\geq \int\limits_{x=\psi>0}^{\infty}(1-1/4x^{2}) 2xe^{-x^2}dx\\
 &\geq (1-1/(4\psi^2))\int\limits_{x=\psi>0}^{\infty}2xe^{-x^2}dx\\
&= (1-1/(4\psi^2))(1-e^{-\psi^2})\\
\end{align}

One other way to think about it (according to comments):
\begin{align}
E[L] &\geq \int\limits_{x=0}^{\infty}\max{(1-1/4x^{2},0)} 2xe^{-x^2}dx\geq 0
\end{align}
which is convergent because

Comment: @kimchilover   Oh, I saw this was a mistake. But, I am correcting it. This is not the main problem.

Comment: The actual singularity has probability zero, so the presence of it does not guarantee that the expectation is not finite. However, there is $O(x^2)$ probability for $X$ to be in the interval $(0,x)$, so the integration for $E[L]$ near $x=0$ behaves like $-\int_0^x 1/y dy$ which diverges.

Comment: @kimchilover I fixed the problem statement.

Comment: ...The information $L \geq 1-(1/4X^2)$ becomes progressively less and less meaningful as $X \to 0$...

Comment: @Ian Thank you for your comment. What you said is exactly what I need to understand. (I see what you say, but cannot understand it and that's why I posted this question). Can you explain more? I have edited the problem statement a little bit.

Comment: @kimchilover Because, from the problem statement, $L$ is a non-negative random variable.

Comment: Which means that really you should be using $L \geq \max \{ 1-1/(4X^2),0 \}$, so that the $0$ kicks in once $X$ dips below $\sqrt{2}$. You have to include all the information you have.